# how do I stop using MSYS MinGW for python?

Tags: windows, mingw, mingw-w64, msys2

sorry for the dumb question, I am a beginner and could barely understand what was going wrong. I installed MinGW to compile c and c++ on VSCode last semester. Now I am doing work with aws, and I had an issue of boto3 never importing even though I kept installing it and seeing the requirement was satisfied. It took me 2 days to learn the issue was boto3 wasn't installed on MSYS and so I installed it there and all was fixed, but I dont want to be using MYSYS for my default python compilation on vscode. How can I fix this?

What I've tried is checking the path on my local system similar to how I change between JDK 11 and JDK 9, but I couldn't tell how to fix it, and am a little apprehensive of uninstalling something without being 100% sure of what I'm doing.